# change object Permission by Metadata API

Tags: apex, metadata-api

I want to change custom object Permission.

i'm using code: [financialforcedev/apex-mdapi](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi)

This is my code but not working even not giving any error.

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService();
MetadataService.Profile admin = new MetadataService.Profile();
admin.fullName = ‘My Standard User’;
admin.custom = true;
MetadataService.ProfileObjectPermissions objPerm = new MetadataService.ProfileObjectPermissions();
objPerm.object_x=’Test__c’;
objPerm.modifyAllRecords = false;
objPerm.allowDelete = false;
admin.objectPermissions = new MetadataService.ProfileObjectPermissions[] {objPerm} ;
List results = service.updateMetadata(new MetadataService.Metadata[] { admin });
MetadataService.handleSaveResults(results[0]);
```

can you help me.

Comment: You don't elevate any permissions? Everything is false.

Comment: To Adrian's point, can you confirm that you are trying to remove the `modifyAllRecords` and `allowDelete` permissions but they remain unchanged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution.

Following Parameters Required:

object_x, allowCreate, allowDelete, allowEdit, allowRead, modifyAllRecords, viewAllRecords

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService();
    MetadataService.Profile admin = new MetadataService.Profile();
    admin.fullName = 'My Standard User';
    admin.custom = true;
    MetadataService.ProfileObjectPermissions objPerm = new MetadataService.ProfileObjectPermissions();
    objPerm.object_x='Test__c';
    objPerm.allowCreate = false;
    objPerm.allowDelete = false;
    objPerm.allowEdit = false;
    objPerm.allowRead = false;
    objPerm.modifyAllRecords = false;
    objPerm.viewAllRecords = false;
    admin.objectPermissions = new MetadataService.ProfileObjectPermissions[] {objPerm} ;

    //System.assert(false,admin);
    List<MetadataService.SaveResult> results = 
        service.updateMetadata(
            new MetadataService.Metadata[] { admin });
    handleSaveResults(results[0]);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what was the issue actually?? and what fixes you applied?? to help the community.

Comment: These Parameters Required:

object_x, allowCreate, allowDelete, allowEdit, allowRead, modifyAllRecords, viewAllRecords